# PR depressions on ECG when a patient has pericarditis

Tags: medical-device, electrocardiogram

Can someone please explain why PR depressions are seen on an ECG when a patient has pericarditis?

That is, from an electrophysiological perspective:

> What are the exact changes on the cell membrane which cause this specific manifestation/presentation on the ECG?

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require some degree of prior research when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?